# SWT CTabItem meaning of setData and setControl

Tags: java, swt, controls, directory, ctabitem

I started with SWT programming and I am trying to reprogram [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Createsatabbeddisplaywithfourtabsandafewcontrols.htm), where `CTabItem`'s are created within a `CTabFolder`. But since I am a very noob in GUI programming, some things are very unclear to me.

What is the purpose of `setData()` and `setControl()` for a `CTabItem`? In which cases or for which situations I use these methods? I have read the API documentation for setData, which says:

`Sets the application defined widget data associated with the receiver to be the argument. The widget data is a single, unnamed field that is stored with every widget.`

But I don't understand this and also the documentation for `setControl`. Can anyone please explain me the purpose of these methods?

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry for not answering. Your answer helped a lot. I got out that for my case I did not need setData as I understood its meaning but setControl is very important for me and now with your help I could handle my task :). Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setData(Object)` and `setData(String, Object)` methods are used to add additional data to a `Widget`. This data can later be accessed. Examples for this use are if you want to identify the widget later on or if you need this additional information someplace else.

The `setControl(Control)` method assigns the content to the item. This means if you call `item.setControl(myContent)`, this `myContent` will be shown if `item` is selected by the user.

---

Example answers that suggest using `setData()`:

- [Swt combobox name/key pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922681/swt-combobox-name-key-pair)
- [How to attach data to TreeItem in SWT/Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599606/how-to-attach-data-to-treeitem-in-swt-java)
- [HTML "getElementByID" implementation for SWT widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735485/html-getelementbyid-implementation-for-swt-widget/11741548#11741548)